# Sentence Construction with put up

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, phrasal-verbs, spoken-english

So yesterday I was driving my friend back to his home and he wasn't sure where we were. So I asked him

"put up your address on Google maps"

Now I am wondering if the sentence above is correct or not.

Also Whilst writing this question I am also wondering if

"I was driving my friend back to his home"

is correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

The "put up" is not a usual form. It would probably be understood by most English speakers. You might choose to say "pull up" or "type in" or any of several other forms. There are lots.

Heh heh. Maybe you want to say you were driving your *car* with your friend *in* the car. You were giving your friend a ride home. I don't suppose you were driving your friend. Though it would be easily understood. It is quite common to say such things as "I gave him a drive home." It contains both the fact that you are helping your friend and that you are using your car. Certainly in conversation this would bother very few people.